# Using "import" versus "from" when importing macros into a Twig template and then extending it

Tags: symfony, twig

When you import a macro into a Twig template and then extend that template, the macro can be used by the child. For example, we define a macro:

`ExampleBundle::macros.html.twig:`

```
{% macro echoSomeText(input) %}
{{ input }}
{% endmacro %}
```

In our template that we plan to extend, we import the macro:

`ExampleBundle::base.html.twig:`

```
{% import 'ExampleBundle:macros.html.twig' as macros %}
```

And in some template, we extend the base template and use the macro:

`ExampleBundle::othertemplate.html.twig:`

```
{% extends 'ExampleBundle::base.html.twig' %}

{{ macros.echoSomeText('Hello!') }}
```

This all works fine. However, if I change the base template to use a `from` tag instead of `import`:

```
{% from 'ExampleBundle:macros.html.twig' import echoSomeText %}
```

I am no longer able to access the macro in the child template.

I have tried to find and understand the documentation around this, but I haven't had much luck. My assumption is that this is not a bug but rather has to do with how Twig handles namespacing and the `import ... as` syntax inserts the macro into the extensible namespace as a variable, but that's just a guess.

Does anybody know the answer as to why these tags behave differently, and how exactly it works?

What I am ultimately looking for is a clean way to import a number of commonly used macros into a base template that I can then use throughout child templates, but without assigning each one a unique name. In other words I am trying to avoid calling them via `macroA.macroName`, `macroB.otherName`, etc. and would prefer to just call them as `macroName` and `otherName` and so on.